# How to fix Docker volume mount

Tags: docker, nginx, volume, docker-volume

I try to build app using nginx:alpine image. I must have access to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/ but any possible solution throw some errors. Current version of script:

```yaml
docker volume create -d local \
    --name server_source \
    --driver=local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt o=bind \
    --opt device=/home/mclotos/Documents/sources/server; \
docker volume create -d local \
    --name logs \
    --driver=local \
    --opt type=tmpfs \
    --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000  \
    --opt device=/home/mclotos/Documents/framework/logs; \
docker volume create -d local \
    --name nginx_conf \
    --driver=local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt device=/home/mclotos/Documents/framework/conf/nginx; \
docker run -dit \
    -v server_source:/var/www/html:ro \
    -v nginx_conf:/etc/nginx \
    -v logs:/var/log \
    --name server \
    nginx:alpine;
```

Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount /home/mclotos/Documents/framework/conf/nginx:/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx_conf/_data: no such device.

Comment: Those file paths sound like you're trying to use Docker volumes instead of building a custom image.  Can you `COPY` your source code and Nginx configuration into an image, use the default logging to stdout, and remove all of these volumes?

Comment: COPY does not solve the problem. i want to be able to change nginx config after containers start.

Comment: No need to create the volumes upfront… Try with `docker run -dit -v /home/mclotos/Documents/framework/conf/nginx:/etc/nginx --name server nginx:alpine`.

Comment: I tried this option, but it gets destroyed after the container dies
```docker run -dit \
    --mount type=bind, \
          source=/home/mclotos/Documents/framework/conf/nginx, \
          target=/etc/nginx \
    nginx:alpine